# What does little lock on desktop icons mean?

Tags: unix, gnome, solaris

I have a fresh installation of Oracle Solaris 10, when I login as user `root`, desktop icons all look fine.

I created a new user called`howard` and logged in using `howard`. All desktop icons have a little "lock" on top right corner.

User `howard` belongs to group `staff` and additional group `root`.

What does the little lock mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the currently logged-in user does not have write access to those files.